# @ConfigurationProperties on inherited variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a superclass that looks like this

```
public class MyProvider {
    private Integer id;
    private ProviderAccount account;
}
```

An extending class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "provider.custom")
public class CustomProvider extends MyProvider {
//this should have CustomProviderAccount
}
```

config for `provider.custom`

```
provider.custom.account.index=1
provider.custom.account.enabled=false
provider.custom.account.description=New Live
```

Account classes

```
public class ProviderAccount {
    private Integer index;
}

public class CustomProviderAccount extends ProviderAccount {
    private boolean enabled;
    private String description;
}
```

When I try to cast `CustomProvider.getAccount()` from `ProviderAccount` to `CustomProviderAccount` I get an exception that I cannot cast.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.bean.hrs.ProviderAccount cannot be cast to
>   com.triphop.bean.hrs.CustomProviderAccount at
>   com.triphop.service.HRSServiceImpl.test(HRSServiceImpl.java:205)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Any idea how can I achieve this in Spring?

Comment: add the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation isn't `@Inherited`. You would need to define it on your child class to achieve what you are looking to do.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html

Rather than using extension you could just create a generic wrapper for the values and create a Map for each type of `provider`.