# How to read @ConfigurationProperties for different prefixes in single class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have 2 different application.yaml at github for spring-boot application. Below are the sample content for both :

`first application.yaml :
    application:
      name: sample-service
 second application.yaml :
    common:
      kafka:
        topic: test`

I created one Configuration class`(abc.java) with @ConfigurationProperties( prefix='common.kafka')` and 
another Configuration class`(xyz.java) with @ConfigurationProperties( prefix='application')`

Here in xyz.java, I am inheriting abc.java. While executing xyz.java, I am not able to access properties of abc.java, getting NPE. It is achieved if I keep same prefix hierarchy i.e. @ConfigurationProperties( prefix='application')

In short, I want to access both application.yaml configurations in single class of spring-boot micro service. However, I am not able to achieve it. 
Please provide any suggestion to access both properties.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to inherit one class into the another?

Isn't it better to have new class that has the two @ConfigurationProperties annotated classes as properties.

E.g.

```
@Component
public class Properties {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Auworied
    KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
}
```

and just use your Properties.class wherever you need to

Comment: I am inheriting it because it is coming from our internal library which is created to have all common configuration at one place. This library is added as an dependency to project

Comment: @eshaingle as mentioned you can just autowire them as 2 different classes. These are just beans and you have to treat them well via dependency injection ;)

Comment: agree but in a library we don't want to have Bean concept. Its just a regular library

Comment: Well, in my opinion, when you are using @ConfigurationProperties on classes in your library you are already into the Bean concept. Your problem is with Annotation inheritance, please refer to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541414/2897455)